# React native webview Android cache issue

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a react native app in which we are using the RNW v13.6.0. We recently migrated to the latest version of RNW. We have a react application that we are trying to load. On Android, we are experiencing a problem where our chunks loading is getting stalled for a long time. We don't see this issue in iOS.

Upon playing with the cache props of the webview, below is what helped with the issue

```
cacheEnabled={!IS_ANDROID}
cacheMode={IS_ANDROID ? 'LOAD_NO_CACHE' : 'LOAD_DEFAULT'}
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what's going on here? I thought default caching should be better.